# Laravel CSV Import inserting with the same ID (Simple Import)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, laravel-excel

This is my store method which grabs the file and loops through each of the rows:

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::file('statuses');
        $filename = $input->getRealPath();
        $i = 0;

        $rows = Excel::load($filename, null, 'ISO-8859-1')->get()->toArray();

        foreach($rows as $k => $row)
        {
            if(!isset($err)) {
                if (!$this->repository->create($row))
                    $err = 'Error importing row ' + $i;
                    $i++;
                }
        }

        if(isset($err)) {
            Flash::error($err);
            return Redirect::route('admin.importstatus.index');
        }

        Flash::success('Statuses Imported!');
        return Redirect::route('admin.statuses.index');
    }
```

In my repository, my create method looks like this:

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    // Create the model
    $model = $this->model->fill($data);

    if ($model->save()) {
        return $model;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, what appears to be happening when I import 6 rows only the final is actually getting inserted into the DB.

If I var_dump in my create method, I am being returned the following:

```
    array (size=7)
  'content' => string 'Imported two' (length=12)
  'status' => float 0
  'user_id' => float 1
  'pinned' => float 0
  'updated_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'created_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'id' => int 8
array (size=7)
  'content' => string 'Imported three' (length=14)
  'status' => float 0
  'user_id' => float 1
  'pinned' => float 0
  'updated_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'created_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'id' => int 8
array (size=7)
  'content' => string 'Imported four' (length=13)
  'status' => float 0
  'user_id' => float 1
  'pinned' => float 0
  'updated_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'created_at' => string '2015-06-28 16:13:22' (length=19)
  'id' => int 8
```

Notice how each of the ID's are all no. 8 (The next available row in the table). The tables ID is defo AUTO INCREMENT etc so no issues there, I guess its a logic issue? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using the same instance of a model over and over.

Try changing fill():

```
$this->model->fill($data);
```

with create():

```
$this->model->create($data);
```

With fill() you are only filling the already created model instance with some data. But if you use create() you are first creating a new instance (with a new id), then filling it with data and then saving it.

### Important

When using **create()** you are also persisting it to the database, which means you don't have to **save()** it manually.

Comment: Perfect! How/why do these differ? Will swapping these to out have any consequences in terms of a simple CRUD app?